# Using multiple submit button for multiple form

Tags: php

i am making page that will be filled with a lot of entry so i was thinking of splitting it into 3 pages with a previous and next button for submitting.

```
// detecting post data
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Step1"])){ 
    displayStep1();
}
else if(isset($_POST["Step2"])){ 
    displayStep2();
}
else if(isset($_POST["Step3"])){ 
    displayStep3();
}
// displaying thanks and dumping all variable
else if(isset($_POST["Thanks"])){ 
    displayThanks();
}
else{
    displayStep1();
}

//function to set value of input box with $_POST data
function setValue( $fieldName ){
    if(isset($_POST[$fieldName])){
        echo $_POST[$fieldName];
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
// step 1 form
function displayStep1(){?>
<form method="POST">
    <h1>This is step 1</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="txtm" values="<?php setvalue("txtm")?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="txtl" values="<?php setvalue("txtl")?>">
    Enter first name<br>
    <input type="text" name="txtf" value="<?php setvalue("txtf")?>"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Step2" value="Step2">
</form>
<?php }

//step 2 form
function displayStep2()
{?>
    <form method="POST">
        <h1>This is step 2</h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtf" values="<?php setvalue("txtf")?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="txtl" values="<?php setvalue("txtl")?>">
        Enter middle name<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtm" value="<?php setvalue("txtm")?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Step1" value="Step1">
        <input type="submit" name="Step3" value="Step3">
    </form>
    <?php }

// step 3 form
function displayStep3()
{?>
    <form method="POST">
        <h1>This is step 3</h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtf" values="<?php setvalue("txtf")?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="txtm" values="<?php setvalue("txtm")?>">
        Enter Last name<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtl" value="<?php setvalue("txtl")?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Step2" value="Step2">
        <input type="submit" name="Thanks" value="Thanks">
    </form>
    <?php }
    
// thanks and dump data
    function displayThanks(){?>
    <h1>Thanks for submitting information</h1><br>
    <?php var_dump($_POST);
}?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this code should make us fill in step 1, and then on submitting, will go into step 2 but with 2 buttons, step 1 and step 3. but my problem is that, after submitting data on step 1, at the page of step 2, clicking the button to go to step 1 will go back to step 1 but the input box is empty. which in theory should be filled with $_POST data from step 1.

in the vardump, there is only data for "txtl" which is the last one to be entered. where did i go wrong?

Comment: If you are making a post request while submitting form in step1 then you should use client side navigation to go to step2 and step3  with prev and next button  and on step 3 you can submit the form finally and save it to database. Moreove you can use save draft button by clicking on that button you can save that form data temporarily in session or in different table and after submit you need to clear that draft data from where you save it early.

Comment: But if you are using through server side post then you need to modify implementation. For each step you need to save data in database and then fetch data from database to show in previous step. It will not come automatically in your form after navigated to previous step.

Comment: could you take a look at this video. maybe its because i cant understand the language as well @VirenderKumar. i copied the exact code and hers was working well. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWgdvySfn3w&t=298s)